# How to insert value in a column using the lit in Spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have Spark dataframe. I am trying to insert value in new column using `lit`, but the value is not being inserted.

Example:

I am trying below code:

```
df:

+--------------------+----------+---------+
|         Programname|Projectnum|     Drug|
+--------------------+----------+---------+
|Non-Oncology Phar...|SR0480-000|Invokamet|
+--------------------+----------+---------+
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df=df.withColumn("CDE_rec_crdt_dt", lit([str(x.CDE_rec_crdt_dt) for x in df_active.select('CDE_rec_crdt_dt').distinct().collect()][0]))

The value of -
[str(x.CDE_rec_crdt_dt) for x in df_active.select('CDE_rec_crdt_dt').distinct().collect()][0] ---'2020-12-03'
```

Desired output:

```
df:

+--------------------+----------+---------+----------------+
|         Programname|Projectnum|     Drug|CDE_rec_crdt_dt | 
+--------------------+----------+---------+----------------+
|Non-Oncology Phar...|SR0480-000|Invokamet|2020-12-03      |
+--------------------+----------+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: what do you mean by `value is not inserting`? what error did you get?

Comment: What is the value of df_active and why are you trying to collect it? Maybe you should join against that dataframe instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val = str(df_active.select('CDE_rec_crdt_dt').distinct().collect()[0][0])
df = df.withColumn(
    "CDE_rec_crdt_dt",
    lit(val)
)
```

Comment: still getting blank.

Comment: could you show me the output of `print(df_active.select('CDE_rec_crdt_dt').distinct().collect()[0][0])`?

Comment: >>''2020-12-03"

Comment: Or try `df.crossJoin(df_active.select('CDE_rec_crdt_dt').distinct())`